# Can't Access App_Code and App_Data on IIS

Tags: asp.net, database, iis, web-config

I just published my ASP.NET Website on IIS and have already configured it to be working, everything is running smoothly.

Except.. I can't accept the App_Data file where all my database information is stored. That might not be the only folder that i can't access but maybe possibly App_Code too? Where i place all my Data Access Object classes (CRUD).

I searched high and low on blogs, articles and stackoverflow but i still can't find the solution to accessing the folders.

I also read that by default certain file extensions are being blocked by IIS

These are some hopefully useful information..

It appears that App_Data and App_Code folders are empty..

[image: Error 1]

Codes in Web.config file from Published Directory
Have some issues copying the codes..**

[image: Error 2]

File Segments in IIS

[image: Error 3]

ConnectionStrings in IIS

[image: Error 4]

Error i'm getting..
[image: Error 5]

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what you can try to isolate the issue.

- Enable **Failed Request tracing** for the website for which you are seeing this failure.
- This will help you determine where the error might be coming from.

Looking at the call-stack you provided, it seems that there is a different issue. I would suggest you to debug the web app on the server to understand what the problem is. Refer the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt621540.aspx